# Escape windows repair install and start in normal boot?

Tags: windows-server-2003, dell-poweredge, windows-server-2003-r2, corruption

I have a corrupted file in the OS (running a poweredge t410, windows server 2003 RT). Booting up in safe mode shows it stopped at acpitabl.dat. Google results led me to believe that the update.sys file was corrupted. So I tried to load it on the disk, but I was having trouble: "unable to create file update.sys 0 files expanded"

So instead of going into recovery console from the installation disk, I entered "install windows" ... where It would detect the previous installation and repair it.

As I did that, I realized that I wasn't using the original installation disk (for licensing reasons, one is standard edition the other is R2), when I switch out the disk I receive a signature error.

When I try to access the recovery console now, it no longer asks me for the administrator password, which means I can't write files on the disk. However I can read them. When I try to boot up without the disk, it leads me the Windows Repair Installation window and then asks for the disk.

Is there anyway out of this, or did I dig myself a hole?

TLDR; I forced a windows OS installation repair due to a corrupt file in the OS, I want to escape the repair installation (e.g. http://0.tqn.com/d/pcsupport/1/5/H/0/-/-/xpnew10.jpg)

Comment: I suspect it's time to restore your backups.

Answer (score 1):

Reboot it with the proper install CD in it and start the repair install properly.

Comment: Ok thanks @mfinni ... however for some reason when I put the correct installation disk in, instead of showing the previous windows installation, it shows a list of partitions. When I select the partition where the OS is on, it no longer allows me to repair it. Am I doing something wrong here?

*edit* grammar

Comment: The screen you're showing in that pic is of Windows XP. You sure you've got the right media now?

Comment: Yea that wasn't an image of my screen, just one in general demonstrating the "repair installation" screen that I was referring to -- to clarify. Although it probably didn't help that it was XP ;)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finishing the repair installation with the first disk -- and then repeating the repair installation with the correct disk. A bit redundant, but it worked!